# Ajenti V Website Custom configuration

Tags: nginx

I'm having a problem with Ajenti V Website Custom configuration

I need to enable this directive for one of my websites:

```
client_max_body_size 8M;
```

If i try to put this

```
http {
   client_max_body_size 8M;
}
```

in Custom configuration or in Custom top level configuration, but after that, nginx stops to work
and if I type:

```
nginx -t
```

it shows this:

```
nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/xxxxx.conf:18
```

Where I should put this directive?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to just put

> client_max_body_size 8M;

whithout "**http{**" and "**}**"

Answer (score 0):

on nginx.conf there's the line:

```
include /etc/nginx.custom.d/*.conf;
```

inside http directive, which means you can create a file with

```
nano(or vi, whatever) /etc/nginx.custom.d/myconf.conf
```

and put your configuration in there.